# Same page displayed for two different options

Tags: support, meta, homepage

When I log-in to meta stackoverflow, I saw a page similar like:

[image: Login Active]

It shows that the **active tab** is selected, but the **question button** not enabled in the screen.

But when I select the **question button** and **active** together it shows the same page as below, but the question button is selected here:

[image: Question Active]

But both tabs are in different positions and displayed under different tabs but it shows same page (Have some changes - in user cards only)

How can I get the first **active** page ? Where it is listed ?

Comment: Click on the big "meta stack overflow" image.

Comment: @Mat: Thanks for the info. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first page is the homepage (which you can get to by clicking on the site logo, and is where you are generally linked when navigating directly to the site), the second page is the questions page.  They are similar, in that they are listing out questions, but they are not the same page, which is why the questions tab isn't highlighted in the first case.

The homepage hides questions with a score below -5, has a slightly different UI (different user cards, for example) and has different possible sub-tabs that can be selected (i.e. the hot tab is only on the homepage).